# Using foreach to generate computed indices in a plot

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

I have a table with 8 columns, and I want to generate 4 plots (1 vs 0, 3 vs 2, 5 vs 4, and 7 vs 6). I was going to use foreach to generate the plots using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {
\addplot table[x index = \x * 2, y index = \x * 2 + 1]\table
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

where `\table` is a stored table.

But I don't seem to permitted to do arithmetic on the indices. Is there a way to do this ?

Update: not-quite-m WE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
-1.5875 -1.5324 -1.4773 -1.4222 -1.3671 -1.312  -1.2569 -1.2018
-1.5875 -1.5324 -1.4773 -1.4222 -1.3671 -1.312  -1.2569 -1.2018
0.013166    0.013156    0.013147    0.013141    0.013137    0.013135    0.013135    0.013139
0.013156    0.013146    0.013138    0.013132    0.013128    0.013127    0.013128    0.013131
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=,input colnames to=r]\transtable\loadedtable
  \begin{axis}
\foreach \x in {0,...,1} {
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Xcol}{\x * 2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ycol}{1 + \x * 2}
  \addplot[mark=,color=blue] table[x index =\Xcol,y index =\Ycol]\transtable;
}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't test it since you did not provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), but you could try `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\XColumn}{\x*2}`, and then use `x index = XColumn`. Similarly for the `y index`.  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I completely understand. it's just that my data source is a transposed table (hence the not-quite-minimal working example) and it took me a while to extract a meaningful snippet for testing. The above should be testable.

Answer (score 6):

For this case I would just use simple number expressions otherwise you have to use `\pgfmathparse{...}\pgfmathresult` pairs and it would be tedious. Instead do the arithmetic using `evaluate` key and use the resulting macro. There are a few examples in the PGF/TikZ manual :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
5 8 6 4 0 6 7 8
}\mytable
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {
\addplot table[x index=\number\numexpr\x*2\relax,
y index=\number\numexpr\x*2+1\relax] {\mytable};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]